# Excel user form text box event

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I want to code a program that compares two columns in two sheets. The user will input the sheet names and ranges he/she wants to compare. If data are found in both sheets the first sheet will highlight the cells in green indicating that the value is available in the other sheet.

When I run the code it gives a run time '9' `error: subscript is out of range`

Note: When I run the code by entering the sheet name in the code instead of using the text box, it runs the program successfully.

```
 Private Sub FindBtn_Click()

 MsgBox (fromSheetTxtBox) ' it outputs the sheet name
'MsgBox (fromRangeFromTxtBox)
 'MsgBox (fromRangeToTxtBox)
'MsgBox (toSheetTxtBox)
'MsgBox (ToRangefromTxtBox)
'MsgBox (ToRangeToTxtBox)

'Dim toSheet As String
'Set toSheet = toSheetTxtBox.Value

Dim i As Integer
For i = 8 To 9331
    Set cell =       Worksheets(fromSheetTxtBox.Text).range("D8:D1427").Find(What:=Worksheets(toSheetTxtBox.Text).Cells(i, 2), lookat:=xlWhole)
If Not cell Is Nothing Then ' if jde cell value is found in tops then green jde cell
    Worksheets("toSheetTxtBox").Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4

End If
Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & i & " of 9331 " '& Format(i / 9331, "%")
Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `toSheetTxtBox` is a *TextBox*, change this line:

```
Worksheets("toSheetTxtBox").Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
```

to this:

```
Worksheets(toSheetTxtBox).Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
```